# Npm pack / publish: File cannot be found

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I made a CLI tool with node.js that is working fine. Then I wanted to publish it as a npm package which worked fine too. But now there is the following error since a (local) file cannot be found:

> ```
> /usr/lib/node_modules/german-bible-cli/app.js:8
>  if (err) throw err;
>           ^
>
> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './schlachter.json'] {
>  errno: -2,
>  code: 'ENOENT',
>  syscall: 'open',
>  path: './schlachter.json'
> }
> ```

The error happens after I install the published package and try running the following command:

```
$ german-bible-cli
```

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/Sheesher/bible-cli). Thanks for helpin' me :)) ✝

**Edit:** My *package.json* does have the `bin` field specified as follows, although I haven't yet uploaded the current version to GitHub.:

```json
"bin": "app.js"
```

Comment: A CLI tool requires a [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) specified in _package,json_ - your [package.json](https://github.com/Sheesher/bible-cli/blob/master/package.json) doesn't have one. What command did you run before the error message appeared?

Comment: 1. it has a specified bin (i aint upload the current version)
2. german-bible-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following two modifications to your `app.js` file:

1. Change line number 7 from this:

   ```
   fs.readFile("./schlachter.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
   ```

   to this instead:

   ```js
   fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./schlachter.json"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
   ```
2. Import the `path` module by adding the following [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) statement at the top of the file:

   ```js
   const path = require("path");
   ```

---

**Explanantion:**

The aforementioned change utilizes the builtin `path` modules [`resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) method to resolve the following two path segments:

- [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) - the path of the directory that contains your module.
- `./schlachter.json` - the relative path.

This essentially forms an absolute path to the `schlachter.json` file location.